# How to extract text after a url in a string?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a text which looks like below

```
"Here is your result https://polo.felix.com/stat/content/table-1576073323.16.html Please click on the link to see more.."
```

Now I just want to extract the text after the link which is 
`Please click on the link to see more..`

Now it might happen that there might not be any text after the link in which case I should get an empty string.

This is what I tried to do

```
message = "Here is your result https://polo.felix.com/stat/content/table-1576073323.16.html Please click on the link to see more.."

if(message.split('html')[1].trim() !== '') {
    do_something()
}
```

But this is not elegant and if the link ends with something other than `html`, this won't work.

Is there any `regex` that can get content to the right of a url in a text if present or return empty string?

Comment: Try [this one](https://regex101.com/r/Il4fvB/2) `(?:https?:\/{2}\S+\s)(.*)` with results in capture group 1, or [this one](https://regex101.com/r/Il4fvB/1) - works in ECMA2018+ `(?<=https?:\/{2}\S+\s).*`

Comment: are you sure it's always going to end with `.html` ?

Comment: @Nicolas no it can end with anything that's why my solution won't work in such scenarios.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following regex (results in capture group 1):

```
(?:https?:\/{2}\S+\s)(.*)
```

```js
s = 'Here is your result https://polo.felix.com/stat/content/table-1576073323.16.html Please click on the link to see more..'
r = /(?:https?:\/{2}\S+\s)(.*)/
m = s.match(r)
if(m) console.log(m[1])
```

Matches URLs beginning with `http://` or `https://` up to the next space (inclusive), then captures the remainder of the string into the capture group.

---

Or you can use the following regex in ECMA2018+ (V8 engine +) - see browser compatibility for *lookbehind assertions* [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp#Browser_compatibility):

```
(?<=https?:\/{2}\S+\s).*
```

```js
s = 'Here is your result https://polo.felix.com/stat/content/table-1576073323.16.html Please click on the link to see more..'
r = /(?<=https?:\/{2}\S+\s).*/
m = s.match(r)
if(m) console.log(m[0])
```

Does the same as the previous regex, just uses a positive lookbehind to ensure the URL precedes rather than matching it. The regex match is the remainder of the string after the URL.

Comment: Positive lookbehinds cannot have greedy quantifiers in most regex engines

Comment: @NoodleOfDeath that's why I specified the version that it's compatible with and included a link to check browser compatibility (although yes, many still don't support variable length lookbehinds).

Comment: @ctwheels I will go with first option since my browser has some issues with positive lookbehind. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Give this a go.

```js
var str = 'Here is your result https://polo.felix.com/stat/content/table-1576073323.16.html Please click on the link to see more..'
var expr = /https?:\/\/\S+(.*)/g
var match = expr.exec(str)
console.log(match[1])
```

Comment: Fails against URLs with `%?#~:[]@!$&'()*+,;=` in them (all of which can be included in a URL).

Comment: Updated try that